# Asp.NET MVC : redirect to another controller with POST Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, controller

My issue is that i want to make redirection to action in another Controller with POST DATA not a GET

```
RedirectToAction("GenaraleExportPDF", "ExportController", new { 

screendata = json, monTitre = monTitre, file = file, block1 = block1, block2 = block2, block3 = block3, block4 = block4 

});
```

**this example exaplaine the redirection but on GET Action.**

Comment: You need to decorate `GeneraleExportPDF` with `[HttpPost]` in order to accept POST requests? Anyway take a look to the post linked by Arturo

Comment: @Aymeric, according to the possible duplicate, HTTP redirections only work with GET by spec.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez updated meanwhile ;)

Comment: so is there any possibility to get my purpose without redirection ?

Comment: @AHmédNet could you detail a bit more what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), `RedirectToAction` returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

`Redirect` and `RedirectPermanent` will not solve your problem also. The basic difference between them is that `RedirectPermanent` sends the browser an HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently) status code whereas `Redirect` will send an HTTP 302 status code.

You are unable to create redirect with POST.

You can use `Session` for storing and sending data between pages.