# ASP.NET MVC post to controller action from same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on this project that currently has the follow method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Service(string identifier)
```

This function is currently being used by a webpage form

```
 <form method="POST" action="/Connector/Service">
 <input type="hidden" id="identifier" name="identifier" value="@TempData["Identifier"]"/>
```

So Service is used when the user clicks on a button that submits the form on the webpage. The user is taken to this page from another action.
I have to implement a feature where sometimes instead of taking the user to the webpage, the user goes directly to the Service method from the action.

I found this thread when searching: [ASP.NET MVC: RedirectToAction with parameters to POST Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action)

But it seems like that is bad design and returning RedirectToAction with Service actually did not work for me.

```
return RedirectToAction("Service", new {identifier})
```

Upon more search it seems like I actually cannot make a post request from my controller. [Asp.NET MVC : redirect to another controller with POST Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737874/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-another-controller-with-post-action)

Any ideas on what I could do here? I am fairly new to ASP.NET and have no idea what to do at this point. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I agree it is bad design. `"where sometimes instead of taking the user to the webpage"` - What is **sometimes**? That's the missing piece here

Comment: the way you call redirect to action is sending a GET request. But your method is marked as POST only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129335/how-do-you-redirect-to-a-page-using-the-post-verb you should read the accepted answer and see how @Jasonbunting does

Comment: @MarkC. The webpage is a terms and conditions page. The user gets taken to the service from the terms and conditions page; I'm trying to have it so if the user already accepted the terms it'll take them directly to the service instead of the webpage.

Comment: I'm not sure why the person wrote it as POST only, but I'm assuming there was a reason, so I'm worried that it might potentially break more things if I just change it to GET.

Comment: What information does the form post exactly?

Comment: There's a hidden input that gives identifier a value from @TempData["Identifier"].

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="identifier" name="identifier" value="@TempData["Identifier"]"/>, and then theres a submit button. I'm not sure why they're doing it this way

Comment: hey you can call the function like a normal one, like this ` Service(value)`

Comment: @Sherlock hey that worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out I could just call the function directly by doing

```
Service(identifier)
```

I kept thinking I had to use RedirectToAction so that didn't even cross my mind.

Thanks [Sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4827151/sherlock) for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The tag [post] is used only when a form is submited by the view itself, if your page redirect to a controler function from another view than the one your in, you have two option:

1. Use the [get] tag, you will probably have more luck with this tag, although i don't know exactly how it work (this might be edited)
2. Use the tagless function with parameters, if you rediret from another view to a function with a parameter, like `public ActionResult Service(string identifier)` that has no tag, you will automatically reach this function.

   if the parameter haven't been specified, it will simply be NULL.

Comment: For #2, if I take away the Post tag will the view still be able to submit it?

Comment: @SWWilliams No, if you remove the POST you cannot submit data unless you change your form method to a GET. GET is used to retrieve remote data while POST is used to insert/update remote data.

Comment: Is it possible to allow the function to handle both POST and GET requests then?

Comment: No.. you can always make a separate function and call that function in post AND get